# jq: extract a specific key from one object to another

Tags: json, jq

I have two JSON files.

file1.json:

```
{
  "Fruits": [
  {
    "name": "Apple",
    "something_else": 123,
    "id": 652090
  },
  {
    "name": "Orange",
    "something_else": 456,
    "id": 28748
  }
]}
```

file2.json:

```
{
  "Fruits": [
  {
    "weight": 5,
    "id": 652090
  },
  {
    "weight": 7,
    "id": 28748
  }
]}
```

I want to combine objects from both files if they have a common key 'id', but to extract only 'name' property from file1. How do I do that using jq?

This is what I want to get:

```
{
  "Fruits": [
  {
    "name": "Apple",
    "weight": 5,
    "id": 652090
  },
  {
    "name": "Orange",
    "weight": 7,
    "id": 28748
  },
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `Fruits` arrays, group it by `id`, select groups with 2 elements because we want *fruits* present in both files. For each selected group; add `name` field from **first** group element to **second**, and collect results in an array.

```
jq -n '[inputs.Fruits[]]
| reduce (group_by(.id)[] | select(length==2)) as $f
  ([]; . + [$f[1] + ($f[0] | {name})])' file1.json file2.json
```

Note that the order files are given on the command line is important, the file with `name`s should be given before the other.

---

Combining objects with same `id` and extracting a subset of fields is way much easier though:

```
jq -n '[inputs.Fruits[]]
| group_by(.id)
| map(select(length==2) | add | {name, id, weight})
' file1.json file2.json
```

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of ways this could be constructed. Here's another way:

```
$ jq '.Fruits |= (. + input.Fruits | [group_by(.id)[] | add | {name,weight,id}])' \
file1.json file2.json
{
  "Fruits": [
    {
      "name": "Orange",
      "weight": 7,
      "id": 28748
    },
    {
      "name": "Apple",
      "weight": 5,
      "id": 652090
    }
  ]
}
```